# How to map Many to Many projection having Seq in case class

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick-3.0

I am using Slick 3.0 with Play framework with Scala.

The docs says about one to one mapping but i didn't find any solution related to Many To Many relationship

http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/orm-to-slick.html#mapping-configuration

There will transient tables so I made one but the problem is with the projection of main class here is the insight of it

Food Item Class

```
case class FoodItem( id: Int, name : String, 
  description : String , price :Float ,
  customization: Option[Seq[Customization] ]= None )
```

Customization Class

```
case class Customization(id: Int, name : String, price : Float)
```

Class for transient table

```
case class FoodItem_Customization(customization_id : Int , food_item_id : Int )
```

Table for FoodItem

```
class FoodItemTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[FoodItem](tag, "FoodItem") { 
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def description = column[String]("description")
  def price = column[Float]("price")



def * = (id, name,description,price) 
<> ((FoodItem.apply _).tupled, FoodItem.unapply _) //this where i have problem

}
```

When I run program Play gives me error

> No matching Shape found. Slick does not know how to map the given types.
>
> Possible causes: T in Table[T] does not match your * projection. Or you use an unsupported type in a Query (e.g. scala List).
>
> Required level: slick.lifted.FlatShapeLevel

**Which is expected but how to solve this ?**

I also checked this example

https://github.com/ebiznext/slick-macros/wiki/2.-Quick-User-guide#many-to-many-relationship-mapping

but it is for slick 2 and Intellij cannot find symbol ~

So this will not work

```
def * = id ~ name ~description ~ price  
<> ((FoodItem.apply _).tupled, FoodItem.unapply _)
```

Answer (score 1):

It causes error because FoodItem class has `customization` field and FoodItemTable class doesn't have it; it is mismatched.

You need to define each table class and map objects.

This page has a good example.
http://olivebh.com/scala-play-slick.html

Comment: thanks for your answer +1 for example, it was helpful but should i need two separate classes one for DAO and other as POJO this is what example is doing ?

Comment: I guess so. Slick is not ORM but FRM.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314015/how-to-create-entity-relationships-in-slick

BTW you can make DAO and tables (like `FoodItemTable`) with SlickGenerator, so you need to create POJO and repository classes.